# Views exposed Filter by date: month OR year

Tags: views

If i make an exposed filter with a date-field, i can only select date and month together. Not on year or month. How can i make it by year OR month?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to add the same filter twice and set one to a Month granularity and the other to a Year granularity. Then you can rearrange the filters and setup an OR grouping and place the year in that one

Comment: that could sound like a solution, but if you select "month" granularity, the year is automatically added

Comment: Can confirm this does not work out of the box, year is automatically added.